# string.intern not using less memory

Tags: java, string, memory

I have store a large number of strings that are equal. The values are not going to change often.

Since `string.intern()` is supposed to return the reference only, I interned each of a list of 100 million exact same strings, stored in an `ArrayList`.

I expected to see the Java memory go way down, but storing a normal string vs an interned string showed a difference of less than .1%.

Am I missing something or is this expected behaviour?

List generation code

```
    long max = 100000000;
    for(int i =0 ; i < max;i++ ){
        list.add("sometextelidedforbrevity".intern());
    }
```

The memory use without is 1 242 360 KB and with  1 242 184 KB.

Comment: How are you creating these strings?  Show us your code.  It's possible that they may already be interned.

Comment: Are you using string literals, or `new String()`? Because string literals are interned automatically...

Comment: How much memory is being used?

Comment: @cdhowie Edited to show code.

Comment: Like the above comments your strings are already interned automatically because you are using a literal string, hence the same memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literals are interned automatically.  That is, the expression `"sometextelidedforbrevity"` will always, at runtime, become a `String` object reference that has been interned.  Calling `intern()` on an already-interned string is effectively a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

I was using String literals, which I overlooked in the documentation, thanks to cdhowie and Russel Zahniser for the answer in comments.

They were *already* being interned by using literals.

From what I understand the only way to have Strings NOT interned is by new String().